Error de busqueda de librería dinámica de ejecutable de programa escrito en NASM
Problema
Estoy intentando usar una librería dinámica que hice en NASM.
El problema que estoy teniendo es que el ejecutable no es capaz de encontrar la libería y ya he intentado muchísimas cosas.
Acá está la lista de comandos que he usado en orden para generar la librería dinámica.
Primer intento
#! /bin/sh

nasm -felf64 prueba.asm
nasm -felf64 main.asm
ld -shared -soname=libprueba.so -o libprueba.so prueba.o -rpath=.
ld -L . -o main main.o -lprueba -rpath=libprueba.so
./main
rm -f *.o

Errores que me indicaba el sistema
bash: ./main: no se puede ejecutar: no se ha encontrado el fichero requerido
Uso de ldd
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000732eba484000)
libprueba.so => Not found

Segundo intento
nasm -felf64 prueba.asm
nasm -felf64 main.asm
ld -shared -soname=libprueba.so -o libprueba.so prueba.o -rpath=.
ld -L . -o main main.o -lprueba -rpath=$(pwd)
chrpath -r $(pwd) main
./main
rm -f *.o

Errores que me indicaba el sistema
bash: ./main: no se puede ejecutar: no se ha encontrado el fichero requerido
Uso de ldd
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000732eba484000)
libprueba.so => /home/reymon/Documentos/snake-game/test/libprueba.so (0x0000732eba47b000)

Tercer intento
#! /bin/sh

nasm -felf64 prueba.asm
nasm -felf64 main.asm
ld -shared -soname=libprueba.so -o libprueba.so prueba.o -rpath=.
ld -L . -o main main.o -lprueba -rpath=$(pwd)
chrpath -r $(pwd) main
./main
rm -f *.o

echo "/home/reymon/Documentos/snake-game/test" | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libprueba.conf
sudo ldconfig
ldconfig -p | grep libprueba
./main

Los errores son los mismos que el anterior caso.
Código de los archivos ensamblador
prueba.asm
bits 64

global print: function
global exit: function

section .text
print:
    enter 0, 0
    mov rdx, rsi
    mov rsi, rdi
    mov edi, 1
    mov eax, 1
    syscall
    leave
    ret
.pic: dq $ - print ;; Aquí se supone que se indica que es PIC

exit:
    mov eax, 0x3C
    mov edi, 0
    syscall
.pic: dq $ - exit ;; Aquí se supone que se indica que es PIC

main.asm
bits 64

global _start
extern print
extern exit

section .text
    _start:
        mov rdi, msg.pointer
        mov rsi, msg.length
        call print
        jmp exit

section .rodata
    msg:
        .pointer: db "Hola Mundo", 0xD, 0xA, 0x0
        .length: equ $ - msg.pointer

Resultado esperado
Espero poder imprimir "Hola Mundo" con la bibliotéca dinámica.
Razones por las cual no lo hago con una biblioteca estáticas
Mis razones son que tengo otro proyecto escrito completamente en ensamblador y requiero tener bibliotecas dinámicas.
Restricciones
Solo se debe usar ld o gold como linker.
No se debe usar gcc como linker debido a los requisitos del proyecto, ya que mis amigos y yo acordamos no usar gcc como linker.
Notas adicionales
La generación de la biblioteca dinámica es correcta ya que una de las pruebas que hice hace dos meses la puede enlazar siempre y cuando el archivo main sea hecho en C y enlace con gcc

Probe la primera alternativa que muestras, y cuando "ldd libprueba.so" me responde "statically linked". Las páginas que he consultado mencionan usar "PIC" en lugar de "elf64", pero PIC no es una opción válida para nasm. Podrías probar en el sitio en inglés.

El problema es que cuando compilas un programa de esta forma, por alguna razón, ld usa un linker dinámico por defecto que normalmente no existe.
 $ readelf -l main | grep -A2 INTERP
  INTERP         0x0000000000000200 0x0000000000400200 0x0000000000400200
                 0x000000000000000f 0x000000000000000f  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld64.so.1]

Si lo compruebas,  el fichero /lib/ld64.so.1 probablemente no exista en tu sistema. Quizás a ti te salga otro, pero lo más probable es que no exista.
Para solucionar esto, utiliza la opción -I para forzar el uso del linker dinámico que quieras:
$ ld -I /bin/ld.so -o main main.o -L. -l prueba


Llevaba muchotiempo con este error y lo acabas de resolver de una forma sencilla ¿Te puedo besar?
