como crear una plantilla en twilio para enviar archivo media que muestre la imagen no el link de la imagen
Estoy batallando para enviar una imagen por whatsapp utilizado twilio, al realizar la palntilla si ingreso variables como {{1}} y {{2}} donde 1 es el nombre y 2 es la url de
la imagen se envia pero muestra el link de la imagen, quiero que muestre la imagen como
tal, como lo hago, estou utilizando django para enviar el mensaje

Muestra el codigo de lo que estas haciendo para tener un [mre] al menos

Esta otra pregunta te servirá como ejemplo para completar la tuya: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/628788/error-de-busqueda-de-librer%c3%ada-din%c3%a1mica-de-ejecutable-de-programa-escrito-en-nasm Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta para completar la información.
