Hacer lista con list comprehension
Necesito hacer una lista como está: [num_1, num_2, num_3,...], hasta 100 con una list comprehension. No tengo ni idea de cómo, ¿podéis ayudarme?

Tienes que esforzarte. Si tropiezas con una piedra no podrás subir la montaña.

Mis disculpas. Después de muchos esfuerzos, fue la solución que encontré. No se volverá a repetir

print([i for i in range(1,100)])

O, si literalmente necesitas num_i, así:
print([f'num_{i}' for i in range(1,100)])

Y obtendrás:
['num_1', 'num_2', 'num_3', 'num_4', 'num_5', 'num_6', 'num_7', 'num_8', 'num_9', 'num_10', 'num_11', 'num_12', 'num_13', 'num_14', 'num_15', 'num_16', 'num_17', 'num_18', 'num_19', 'num_20', 'num_21', 'num_22', 'num_23', 'num_24', 'num_25', 'num_26', 'num_27', 'num_28', 'num_29', 'num_30', 'num_31', 'num_32', 'num_33', 'num_34', 'num_35', 'num_36', 'num_37', 'num_38', 'num_39', 'num_40', 'num_41', 'num_42', 'num_43', 'num_44', 'num_45', 'num_46', 'num_47', 'num_48', 'num_49', 'num_50', 'num_51', 'num_52', 'num_53', 'num_54', 'num_55', 'num_56', 'num_57', 'num_58', 'num_59', 'num_60', 'num_61', 'num_62', 'num_63', 'num_64', 'num_65', 'num_66', 'num_67', 'num_68', 'num_69', 'num_70', 'num_71', 'num_72', 'num_73', 'num_74', 'num_75', 'num_76', 'num_77', 'num_78', 'num_79', 'num_80', 'num_81', 'num_82', 'num_83', 'num_84', 'num_85', 'num_86', 'num_87', 'num_88', 'num_89', 'num_90', 'num_91', 'num_92', 'num_93', 'num_94', 'num_95', 'num_96', 'num_97', 'num_98', 'num_99']
Pero para eso tienes ChatGPT o el manual. Stackoverflow es para dudas un poco más complicadas que la IA no te pueda resolver. En cualquier caso, bienvenida
Una list comprehension en Python es una herramienta que permite crear listas de manera concisa y legible. Utiliza una única línea de código para generar una nueva lista aplicando una expresión a cada elemento de un iterable, como una lista, rango o conjunto. También puede incluir condiciones opcionales para filtrar los elementos que se añaden a la lista resultante. Su sintaxis básica es [expresión for elemento in iterable if condición]. Esto reduce la necesidad de bucles for y estructuras más largas, mejorando la eficiencia del código y su claridad. Es muy utilizada en Python para simplificar tareas repetitivas.

Diste una solución sin explicación. El OP quedo igual que antes, sin saber hacer una comprensión.

@CandidMoe Explicación añadida. Saludos

Gracias por la explicación y la solución. No pensé que la página fuera para avanzados, sólo busqué ayuda. Intentaré usar otros medios

@Noe. No es un sitio para "avanzados"; lo único que se pide es esfuerzo. Tu pregunta no demuestra ningún esfuerzo, ningún intento por comprender, ninguna investigación, ningún código como para empezar. Podrías al menos haber mostrado una solución usando un ciclo for, y de ahí preguntar como hacerlo con comprensión de listas.

@Noe Bueno, las IAs le han hecho mucho daño al sitio, antes tenía mucha más actividad y, a veces, que seamos tan exigente tampoco ayuda. Lo importante es que te animes a empezar en esto, a todos nos ha tocado que los puristas nos regañen, ya ves como a mí me han tirado de las orejas en esta misma publicación :)

@Noe Esta pregunta representa lo que se pide en este sitio: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/628788/error-de-busqueda-de-librer%c3%ada-din%c3%a1mica-de-ejecutable-de-programa-escrito-en-nasm
